# Generate a random username using jquery

Tags: jquery

How I can generate unique username from user first name and last name just like twitter does using jquery. I am developing an app which asks first and last name from user to create there profile. I want to have the username automatically made using first/last name, but its must be unique. How I can do it.

Comment: what have you tried? By the way, if you want it "just like twitter does using jquery", i supposed you identified the code there because you know what it uses, why not inspire yourself from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Math.random() function to get random char from unique char string.
Here have an example.

```
function GetUserName()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6);
```